# How to change a spring hibernate maven application to multi model maven project

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, primefaces

I made a web application with maven spring 4 hibernate 4 and primefaces in one web project now i want to make a multi model project : main(packaging pom) presentation(view packaging ear) 
business(packaging war) and integration (for jpa and hibernate) that's alll what i know can someone help me how to do it from the scratch because it's my first time and thx

Comment: Can i please ask you to vote the answer if it helped, even if a bit in late XD! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of which you have spoken is quite good and simple, this tree should reflect it

pom.xml (aggregator, packagin pom)

- EAR-front-end
- WAR-business
- JAR-integration

So let's start from creating your own empty structure, then starting with integration of the various parts of the old structure, beginning from the integration layer...in turn integrates also a solid structure of unit tests, I would not exclude the possibility of dividing even the three main entities, the EAR , the WAR and JAR (integration) in sub-modules to increase the modularity of the application and facilitate the integration and maintenance activities.

I hope this can be a good starting point

Comment: done .. but what i should do with my application context ?

Comment: can you be more specific? what's the problem? Dividing the project into modules does not mean stop him from communicating with each other ...

Comment: i have one file for spring config applicationcontext for all configuration should i split it or i can keep the same ? and another question : i have 3 levels MangedBean , Service nd DAO where should i move the service to the business or the integration ?

Comment: You should split the configuration in order to simplify the project configuration, for the beans, the decision is strictly coupled with the project configuration, so you should give us more particulars